# Python script running under windows over nssm.exe

Tags: python, windows, service, nssm

I have a python script that runs inside this command:

`subprocess.run([driver, '/print:printer=' + printer, filename])`

If the script is run from the command line, everything works (the script is written as a daemon, ie it never ends and waits for data to arrive from the computer network). But if, for the same script, I create a daemon in windows services using `nssm.exe`, the script stops working. Respectively, the `driver` that processes the `file` cannot load its configuration, which is stored in the same directory where the script is in the python daemon, and the `driver` is also located there.

Can you advise what I need to modify so that the driver looking for its configuration file can find it when the configuration file is located in the same location as the driver?
Do I need to modify the `subprocess.run` command somehow?

Here is the directory listing *(C:\Python37)*:

```
PDFXCview.exe                     driver
PDF-XChange Viewer Settings.dat   drivers configuration file
PrinterBirdge.ini                 configuratin file for daemon
PrinterBridge.py                  script daemon
```

PDFXCview.exe does support other parameters on the command line, but none of the parameters were able to force PDFXCview.exe to load the configuration file. However, only if the script runs as a windows service.

Thanks

Jaroslav